# Oracle Divisor is equal to zero

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I wrap a DECODE around this query to handle a zero divisor without computing the denominator summation twice? I don't want to return anything other than `thedate` and the rounded percentage.

```
SELECT thedate, ROUND (100*
  SUM( case when TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= thedate
     AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) >= add_months( trunc(thedate,'mm'), -12) 
     AND trunc(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= trunc(ACTIVITY_NEED_DATE) 
     AND SYSDATE  >=  trunc(thedate,'mm') then 1 else 0 end )  
  /
  SUM( case when TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= thedate 
     AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) >= add_months( trunc(thedate,'mm'), -12) 
     AND SYSDATE  >=  trunc(thedate,'mm') then 1 else 0 end ) ) as OTR12 
       FROM TEST
       cross join (  select add_months(last_day(SYSDATE), level-7) as thedate 
       from dual connect by level <= 12  )  
       GROUP BY thedate 
       ORDER BY thedate
```

It seems with the DECODE, I'd have to do the denominator summation twice
`DECODE(denominator_summation,0,NULL, numerator_summation / denominator_summation)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a subquery?

```
select thedate, (case when denom <> 0 then round(100*num/denom) end)
from (SELECT thedate,
             SUM( case when TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= thedate
                            AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) >= add_months( trunc(thedate,'mm'), -12) 
                            AND trunc(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= trunc(ACTIVITY_NEED_DATE) 
                            AND SYSDATE  >=  trunc(thedate,'mm') then 1 else 0
                  end )   as num,
             SUM( case when TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= thedate 
                        AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) >= add_months( trunc(thedate,'mm'), -12) 
                        AND SYSDATE  >=  trunc(thedate,'mm') then 1 else 0 end ) ) as OTR12 
        FROM TEST cross join
             (  select add_months(last_day(SYSDATE), level-7) as thedate 
                from dual connect by level <= 12  )  
        GROUP BY thedate 
     ) t
order by thedate
```

Comment: The sub query works and I accept it as the answer.  I just noticed the 3rd answer.  Seems they both work.

Answer (score 1):

use a having clause:

```
having 
SUM( case when TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= thedate 
 AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) >= add_months( trunc(thedate,'mm'), -12) 
 AND SYSDATE  >=  trunc(thedate,'mm') then 1 else 0 end ) ) as OTR12 
   FROM TEST
   cross join (  select add_months(last_day(SYSDATE), level-7) as thedate 
   from dual connect by level <= 12  )
> 0
```

Comment: I see two problems here: (1) it will exclude part of the output instead of just showing a default column value; (2) wouldn't you have to repeat this part **twice** (in the body and again in HAVING)?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  thedate, 
  ROUND (
    100 * SUM( 
       case when TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= thedate
       AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) >= add_months( trunc(thedate,'mm'), -12) 
       AND trunc(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= trunc(ACTIVITY_NEED_DATE) 
       AND SYSDATE  >=  trunc(thedate,'mm') then 1 else 0 end 
    ) / nullif(SUM( 
       case when TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) <= thedate 
       AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_END_DATE) >= add_months( trunc(thedate,'mm'), -12) 
       AND SYSDATE  >=  trunc(thedate,'mm') then 1 else 0 end 
    ), 0) 
  ) as OTR12 
FROM 
  TEST
  cross join (  
     select add_months(last_day(SYSDATE), level-7) as thedate 
     from dual connect by level <= 12  
  )  
GROUP BY thedate 
ORDER BY thedate
```

Comment: +1 for your answer.  Gordon's worked in SQLplus and so I accepted it before I saw and tried yours.  However, I ended up using yours because I'm implementing the query using Hibernate in a Java app.  Hibernate returns Gordon's as an array of Strings, yours as an array of BigDecimals, which is what I need it to be. http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mb124283/archive/2007/04/java_persistenc.html